# How to find marks in the image with Firebase ML Kit?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, ocr, firebase-mlkit

I have mobile app for android. I need to process images in my app. This is example images:

[image]

This is a photo of the table with marks. I need to find these marks and their positions. Is it possible to do the test? Is it possible to do with ML Kit for Firebase?

If yes - which api should i use?
 I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/Wr3kg-sUwOk

Comment: I am not sure why you need ML. I would use ML if I needed to differentiate the marks in the cell between a lower letter v, uppercase letter V or an actual check mark. Your use case relates more to image processing. I would use a differential between your virgin template against the marked template and then map the detection coordinates against the initial cell's row/col value.  Another possible approach is to use OCR assuming that all entries are check marks(crosses or circles but not filling the blank). Based on the use case, I would use the former.

Comment: @KF thank you. It is interesting. but can you describe your answer in more detail? I will make a mobile app on flutter. Perhaps you will advise the library.

Comment: Getting the pixel from an image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478321/get-the-pixel-on-which-i-clicked  This would be my start code for the differential approach. This is very manual but doable.

Another suggestion is to bring OpenCV to Flutter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099700/how-to-add-opencv-in-flutter-plugin OpenCV allows pattern detection so I have seen. You can get the corners of each cell first. Then pixel processing per cell.

Related to OCR, Firebase has the capability as text recognition which provides coordinates: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/

Comment: Hi @KF. Please make your comments a answer. I will accept this as the correct answer. You showed me the rigth way :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why you need ML. I would use ML if I needed to differentiate the marks in the cell between a lower letter v, uppercase letter V or an actual check mark. Your use case relates more to image processing. I would use a differential between your virgin template against the marked template and then map the detection coordinates against the initial cell's row/col value. Another possible approach is to use OCR assuming that all entries are check marks(crosses or circles but not filling the blank). Based on the use case, I would use the former.

Getting the pixel from an image, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478321/get-the-pixel-on-which-i-clicked). This would be my initial code for the "differential" approach. This is very manual but doable. Another suggestion is to bring [OpenCV to Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099700/how-to-add-opencv-in-flutter-plugin). **OpenCV** allows pattern detection so I have seen. You can get the corners of each cell first. Then you can do pixel processing per cell. Related to OCR, Firebase has the capability as text recognition which provides coordinates. You can review their docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/).

Comment: I try this package flutter_opencv 0.0.3. But I do not know how to find a rectangle :(, although I learned to find the coordinates of its beginning.

Comment: What docs are you using. What function are you using to get those coordinates?