# How to fix gradle task ':app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders' in flutter gradle build for opencv native with NDK?

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface, build.gradle

I'm setting up a new flutter app and I want to add opencv native (c++) plugin using NDK.

I've installed and configured OpenCV and NDK (using differents [tutorials](https://medium.com/@siantlords/opencv-and-android-ndk-integration-in-android-studio-883a810189e2)) and I got this error while I'm trying to build my project (`flutter run`):

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I don't know where it come from, there is no 'task' `mergeDebugJniLibFolders` in my `build.gradle` from my app.
I can't run flutter with specified arguments : it make errors.

Comment: try to run the `./gradlew assemble --debug --stacktrace --info` to get more logs.

Comment: I tried, here is what I get: `Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders'. at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)` ...trace blabla... `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.android.ide.common.resources.AssetItem.computePath(AssetItem.java:58)` ...trace blabla... None of files in trace come from my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution !

I get in my `build.gradle` those lines:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        ...
    }
 }
```

So I decided to open the `src/main/libs` file which contain only

`../../../../OpenCV-Andoid-sdk/native/libs/`

... a wrong path that should be :

`../../../../sdk/native/libs/`

I put the corect path into the gradle file respecting the new relative path :

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../../sdk/native/libs/']
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        ...
    }
 }
```

And now it compile perfectly ! What a tricky error on which I spend 6 evenings...